# OS X Lion not able to login with regular open directory domain users

Tags: macos, osx-server, leopard, open-directory

I've configured a Lion client machine to connect to my OS X server and use it for network logins. The diradmin works okay, but I tried to use a regular user, and it doesn't allow any other users to log on.

Where can I start to troubleshoot this?

Comment: In the error logs, it shows the password being entered successfully, (logs on the server), so I'm a bit confused. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Can you try another non-admin user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing from your tags this is a 10.5 Server with 10.7 clients?

In your Open Directory user configuration/preferences are you using portable home folders? (With the user in question selected in Workgroup Manager, choose the Preferences button and check the "Mobility" section)

If so (and even if not!), check that your users have a Home path set in Workgroup Manager -> Accounts -> testuser -> Home tab. Usually the diradmin default home is set to `/var` but for other users I've seen it default to (None) which causes the login window to just shake and reject the user when trying to log in on a client system, probably because the system doesn't know where to create their home folder.

Try a test where you set testuser's Home location to `/Users/testuser` by clicking the + in the Home tab of WGM and entering `/Users/testuser` under the Full Path: field (I'm basing this wording off a 10.6 server but I recall 10.4 to 10.6 being all quite similar.)

Good luck!!

Comment: I didn't have home paths for all my users, I noticed when I buggered up the home path for DIRADMIN testing configuring the presets. You got closest, I didn't realise that home folders are required for logons - So ... MrCoBalt, (nice name!) you win! :)

Answer (score 0):

(assuming server is 10.5)

Check out the Service Access Lists (SACLs) on the server under Server Admin -> Settings -> Access. Make sure you aren't restricting access to Login Window (or something similarly named).

Also, is the workstation in the Workgroup Manager? Are any of its preferences being managed, again Login Windows, like what users or groups can use that workstation to login.